# C# WinForms - How to prevent custom control from inherit the form font styling?

Tags: c#, inheritance, styles, font-size

I've searched for days and nothing worked.

I'm working on a project using a custom style for WinForm called MaterialSkin, github page is https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin

Basically to use it, I just change the inherited class from this `public partial class FormMain : Form` to this `public partial class FormMain : MaterialForm` and this applies the Material Design to my project.

The problem is that all controls are affected by this change.
If I add a label, and change it font, the visual change only works in design mode, when I run the project, the MaterialSkin font is applied (Roboto).

Now I want to use a custom control called CircularProgressBar from this repo https://github.com/falahati/CircularProgressBar

And the problem is the same, I want a big number in center of the circle, and it works in design mode.
When I run the project, the font size is reduced to 8,5.

I'm already tried to set the new font manually to the CircularProgressBar in Form_Load event and also in OnPaint, nothing work.

Any ideas about what I missing?

[image: font size changed in runtime overwriting my definition]

### Edit

As suggested by @Jimi, I'm posting the minimal code below to reproduce the problem I'm facing.

1. Created a brand new project `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) v4.6.1`
2. I've searched and installed `MaterialSkin.2 v2.1.3 (not the latest)` by leocb, IgnaceMaes
3. I've searched and installed `CircularProgressBar v2.8.0.16` by Soroush Falahati
4. I've opened `Form1.cs` and made the necessary changes to load MaterialSkin
5. I've added `CircularProgressBar`control to `Form1`, Build and Run.

```cs
// Form1.cs
using MaterialSkin;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;

namespace SimpleTestProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : MaterialForm
    {
        private readonly MaterialSkinManager materialSkinManager = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
            materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
            materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;
        }
    }
}
```

#### The Result

[image: Another running demo showing the problem (bug)]

Comment: Set a different Font, in the Designer. Try `Segoe UI` first. -- When you set the Font explicitly, in a Control, the Font is not inherited. But the Font must be compatible with GDI+ rendering.

Comment: That's the problem, I already tried almost all font options, no one worked, don't even change in run time, only design mode. Segoe UI not work either. And I agree, if a set the font explicitly, the font should't be inherited, but it's inherinting no matter what I do. If I can change the size, it will solve 95% of the problem

Comment: Then there's probably something related to your setup, because this is not the default behavior of a `MaterialForm` or a `MaterialTabControl`. I don't use the CircularProgressBar Control. Try with another Control.

Comment: As I said in my question, even when I try change the font of a simple Label, it doesn't work, but thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: As mentioned, check your configuration. That `ColorScheme` is not the default, so you're resetting it somewhere. I don't know if you're using the `MaterialSkinManager` correctly, but there's a good chance that you're resetting default properties of your Controls.

Comment: Doing some tests here in a brand new WinForm, I noticed that this "bug" only happens when I initialize the MaterialSkin including the method ```materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);``` . If I comment this line out, the CircularProgressBar has no changes in original style.

Comment: You should post your code then. Does the MaterialSkinManager initialization [look like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66566656/7444103)? -- I've tested your CircularProgressBar with that setup and there's no change in Font.

Comment: I've added more detailed informations about what I'm doing.

Comment: Move the declaration of your Manager to a ReadOnly Field, as in `private readonly MaterialSkinManager materialSkinManager = null;`. After `InitializeComponent()`, create the Instance: `materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;`.

Comment: Did it, same result :( This problem are being a pain in the ass. Is there any way to you send me the project you did, and that worked?

Comment: Sure, I can post the (very simple) Form Project to Google Drive. But, I've noticed, now that you've shown the satellite assemblies version, that I use a different version of MaterialSkin: I use the original Library (the Updated version of MaterialSkin v0.2.1, `MaterialSkin.Updated v0.2.2`), you're using `MaterialSkin.2`, which I've never used. I'll test this one, otherwise it's pointless.

Comment: All right, that's a setting in MaterialSkin.2 Manager, `EnforceBackcolorOnAllComponents` that is set to `true` by default. You need to set it to `false` instead: **before** you call `materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);`, set `materialSkinManager.EnforceBackcolorOnAllComponents = false;` -- Keep the `readonly` field declaration.

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of materialSkin.2 Jimi's answer above is correct. Enforce back color was created to solve some backcolors issues with people mixing material skin and default windows forms controls. Disabling this option will make the lib stop messing with other components that are not part of material skin. However, disabling it may cause inconsistent backcolors among mixed controls.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I got busy yesterday, tried the suggestion at night and worked perfectly! Thank you so much @Jimi for your availability to help me, and thanks Leo for your confirmation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Jimi and @Leo, to avoid applying MaterialSkin style to all controls, just need to disable the `MaterialSkinManager` property called `EnforceBackcolorOnAllComponents`

`materialSkinManager.EnforceBackcolorOnAllComponents = false;`